# \draw rectangle TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw

I'm trying to lean TikZ.

I've written the following small document

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{pgf, tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,calc}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\smash{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
            \node[anchor=text, shape=circle,fill,draw,inner sep=0pt,text=white,minimum size=1.4em] (char) {#1\strut};}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
%    \draw(4,-1) rectangle(8,4);
    \foreach \y in {1, ..., 4}
    \foreach \x in {1, ..., 8} {
            \ifthenelse{\equal{\x}{5} \AND \equal{\y}{3}}{\draw(\x,\y)rectangle(0.4cm,0.4cm)}{
            \ifthenelse{\equal{\x}{4} \AND \equal{\y}{2}}{
                \draw[thick] (\x,\y) rectangle (0.4cm,0.4cm);
                \draw(\x,\y)rectangle(0.4cm,0.4cm)}{\draw(\x,\y)circle(0.4cm)}};
    }

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

They output should be a set of 4x8 circles, but the 4th circle of the second row  and then 5th circle of the third row should be replaced by rettangles.

I don't understand why they are as in the picture.

Finally, how can define a command which writes numbers in the circles according to the parameters passed by another document. I taught that I could use the newcommand \circled, but I don't understand how.

Please help me!

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You should use `rectangle ++(0.4cm, 0.4cm)` (or even better, shift it 0.2cm to the left and bottom beforehand). Which kind of number parameter do you want to use?

Comment: Thanks. I would like to have a command like this


\newcommand{\initbao}[1][22,%
                        0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,%
                        0,2,2,6,0,0,0,0,%
                        0,0,0,0,6,2,2,0,%
                        0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,%
                        22]

Comment: @TeXnician Thanks. I would like to have a command like this


        \newcommand{\initbao}[1][22,%
                        0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,%
                        0,2,2,6,0,0,0,0,%
                        0,0,0,0,6,2,2,0,%
                        0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,%
                        22]

The command should put the passed number in the circles.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I recommend using `pic`s for that and not to use `ifthenelse` (for that).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[pics/.cd,
circ/.style={code={\draw (0,0) circle[radius=#1];}},
circ/.default=4mm,
rect/.style={code={\draw (-#1,-#1) rectangle (#1,#1);}},
rect/.default=4mm]
%    \draw(4,-1) rectangle(8,4);
\path    foreach \Y in {1,...,4}
    {foreach [evaluate=\X as \Z using {int(10*\Y+\X)}] \X in {1,...,8} {
     (\X,\Y)
     \ifnum\Z=35    
       pic{rect}
    \else
      \ifnum\Z=24
         pic{rect}
      \else
         pic{circ}
      \fi
    \fi }};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This is what you could do if you want to add the numbers from your list `\initbao` to the scheme.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=12pt]{standalone}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[circ/.style={circle,draw,minimum size=8mm},
rect/.style={rectangle,draw,minimum size=8mm}]
\def\myarray{{22,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 0,2,2,6,0,0,0,0,
   0,0,0,0,6,2,2,0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,22}}
\path    foreach \Y in {1,...,4}
    {foreach [evaluate=\X as \Z using {int(10*\Y+\X)}] \X in {1,...,8} {
     (\X,\Y)
     \ifnum\Z=35    
       node[rect] {\pgfmathparse{\myarray[(\Y-1)*8+\X-1]}\pgfmathresult}
    \else
      \ifnum\Z=24
          node[rect] {\pgfmathparse{\myarray[(\Y-1)*8+\X-1]}\pgfmathresult}
      \else
          node[circ] {\pgfmathparse{\myarray[(\Y-1)*8+\X-1]}\pgfmathresult}
      \fi
    \fi 
    }};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or a command version thereof (with the ordering changed).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=12pt]{standalone}

\newcommand{\initbao}[1]{\begin{tikzpicture}[circ/.style={circle,draw,minimum size=8mm},
rect/.style={rectangle,draw,minimum size=8mm}]
\path    foreach \Y in {1,...,4}
    {foreach [evaluate=\X as \Z using {int(10*\Y+\X)}] \X in {1,...,8} {
     (\X,\Y)
     \ifnum\Z=35    
       node[rect] {\pgfmathparse{{#1}[(4-\Y)*8+\X-1]}\pgfmathresult}
    \else
      \ifnum\Z=24
          node[rect] {\pgfmathparse{{#1}[(4-\Y)*8+\X-1]}\pgfmathresult}
      \else
          node[circ] {\pgfmathparse{{#1}[(4-\Y)*8+\X-1]}\pgfmathresult}
      \fi
    \fi 
    }};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}

\initbao{22,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 0,2,2,6,0,0,0,0,
   0,0,0,0,6,2,2,0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,22}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much. Can you help me to create a new command to put numbers into the circles/rettangles. The numbers will be different depending on the document which uses the new command.

Comment: @user183677 I added a version that uses your numbers from the `\initbao` command from your [above comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/484197/draw-rectangle-tikz/484259?noredirect=1#comment1224364_484197) to the scheme.

Comment: thanky very much. But I would like to transform the group \begin{tikzpicture}...\end{tikzpicture} in a command with the numbers as parameters.

Comment: @user183677 Added.

Comment: Thank you very much. I wrote a sty file which uses PSTrick but since 2014 it doesn't work. Now thanks to you I can write another sty file using TikZ, which I have to understand well! Nino

Comment: @user183677 I was using pstricks for many years but switched to Ti*k*Z roughly two years ago. In the beginning it is a bit unusual but now I cannot switch back. (If the answer solved your problem, could you perhaps consider accepting it by clicking the check mark left of it?)

Comment: I realized that your code doesn't display the number in the correct order, i.e. it shows the rows from the last one, while they should be displayed in the exact order indicated in the command \initbao! I've tried to correct the code but I failed to understand \pgfmathparse

Comment: @nino_user183677 `\pgfmathparse` just allows us to extract elements of an array, so `\pgfmathparse{<array>[<index>]}` makes  `\pgfmathresult` become the element of the array at index position `<index>`. (You could also use `\pgfmathsetmacro{\myelement}{<array>[<index>]}` to assign this value to `\myelement`.) Anyway, I changed the ordering in the command version.

Answer (score 2):

In place to use a loop and conditionals you can use `matrix of nodes` where all the nodes are circles and style some of them as rectangles.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzstyle{r}=[rectangle] % <-- because I like tikzstyle ;)
    \matrix[matrix of nodes, nodes in empty cells,
      column sep={1cm,between origins},row sep={1cm,between origins},
      nodes={circle,anchor=center,draw,minimum size=8mm}](M){
      & & &             &       & & &   \\
      & & &             & |[r]| & & &   \\
      & & & |[r,red]| ? &       & & &   \\
      & & &             &       & & & ! \\
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you perhaps consider stopping picking on me?

Comment: Could you be more precise what is your "original" idea that I have stolen from you ?

Comment: I did not say you stole anything.

Comment: What are you talking about in this case ?

Comment: Your behavior to, whenever you see a chance, to pick on me.

Comment: Sorry I don't get it (really). Could you be more precise in this particular case what I've done wrong ?

Comment: Well, when the question changes, as it did because the OP asked for something additional/different or new in the comments, rather than giving the one who got the comment a chance to address it, immediately write an answer that addresses this. That's called picking.

Comment: When I see a question and a way to answer it differently from existing answers, if I have time, I add a new answer. It's as simple as that. I don't care if the question is changed or not. We are not competing here, we are here just to help people.

Comment: Although you like `\tikzstyle` you should note that it is deprecated and should not be used for several reasons…

Comment: @TeXnician I do not agree with you and with lot of other users. I know very well [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52372) but I don't understand how we conclude from this that we should not use it. I have never seen a single problem due to `\tikzstyle`.